# How to do jQuery form Validation of html elements before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I want to do form validation for all three tags and after validation, enable the submit button until validation is done not to enable submit button.

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="js/moment.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="report-form">
      <div id="report-pane" class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <label>Report:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <select class="form-control" id="report">
            <option value="" selected>Select Report</option>
            <option id="rep1" value="10">Report 1</option>
            <option id="rep2" value="20">Report 2</option>
            <option id="rep3" value="30">Report 3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--Date Section-->
      <div id="date-pane" class="row">
        <!--Script for datepicker-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function() {
            var now = new Date();
            var yearsold = new Date();
            yearsold.setFullYear((now.getFullYear() - 2));

            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
              format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
              startDate: yearsold,
              endDate: now
            });

            var defaultDate = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');
            $("#datePicker1").val(defaultDate);
            $("#datePicker2").val(defaultDate);

          });

        </script>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <label>Start Date:</label>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-3'>

          <input class="datepicker form-control" type="text" id="datePicker1" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <label>End Date:</label>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-3'>

          <input class="datepicker form-control" type="text" id="datePicker2" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="button-pane" class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary">Generate Report</button>-->
          <input type="submit" id="requestBtn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Generate Report"></input>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

          // Validation Function Needed
        });

      </script>
    </form>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Enable the submit button only if all the form validation is done

Example
 [image: Sample Visual]

Comment: Try going for angular, It can do the job in under 15 mins

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#ccSelectForm').validate({
    rules: {
        inputEmail: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        inputEmailConfirm: {
            equalTo: '#inputEmail'
        }
    }
});

$('#ccSelectForm input').on('keyup blur', function () {
    if ($('#ccSelectForm').valid()) {
        $('button.btn').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('button.btn').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

});

[Check this link](http://jsfiddle.net/p628Y/1/)

Comment: You suggest adding jquery.validat.js for this simple validation each byte is costly.. And also prop disabled false is invalid

Comment: Why i suggest is that because he already used J query in his code.

Comment: @ShintuJoseph And in the question he clearly mentioned that how to do in jquery.

Comment: Yes but not jquery.validate. Js

Comment: All the scripts are very similar and validate is a predefined robost function so we have to use this functionality.

Comment: Validate is not a predefined function with jquery, it comes with jquery.validate.js robust code is needed for more complex situations not for merely validating 3 fields, adding a 23Kb plugin is heavy

Comment: Yes yes validate function is given by jquery so its belongs to jquery api. And now a days every web-applications is depend upon jquery for fronted work also its very easy to use every where.

Comment: It is a separate library not a part of jquery

Comment: Yes iam aware of that, see github it is not a part of the jquery project , do you need a 23Kb plugin to write 10 lines of code

Answer (score 0):

i think you want something like this

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
// before validation
$("#submit").attr("disabled","disabled");
// after validation
$("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on Jq custom logic is needed,

```
var validationCallBk = function(){
    var report = $('#report').val();
    var startDate = $('#datePicker1').val();
    var endDate = $('#datePicker2').val();
    if(report != '' && startDate == somevaliddate && endDate == somevaliddate)
         //enable btn
    else
        //disable btn
};
$('#report').on('change',validationCallBk);
//use the datepicker on select event and call validationCallBk
```